# Display other directories with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

By default, Android Studio displays only `manifest`, `java` and `res` directories, plus several files under `Gradle Scripts`.

I also put some files under `app/src/main/MYLANGUAGE` and would like to process them with gradle script. Unfortunately, I don't see this directory in Android Studio. Is it possible to see something additionally to Android template in the pane?

Comment: Do you just want to see your file in the file tree displayed in Android Studio OR include it in the files that Gradle builds, or BOTH?

Comment: Just see. I will write Gradle task to process these files manually.

Comment: Ok. And I see that you've solved it already. So, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I found dropdown

[image]

in `Project Pane` and in `Project` mode it shows everything.